# WebView Authentication from Menu Preferences - Android

Tags: android, xml, authentication, webview

i'm doing an Android App which uses WebView and onStartUp it loads an Url which i have given in the onCreate method. The Url need Authentication, i need to provide user to give credentials(Username, Password). So in the menu settings, i have given two options, "Settings" and "Exit". In the "Settings" option, i have given URL, Username and Password. I want to pass these values in onReceivedHttpAuthRequest() method to Authenticate User, but its not working. I tried my level best in surfing Internet and finally i'm here. I'm giving my code below. Please guide and correct me. This project is IMPORTANT! to me.

BaiBrower.java

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.webkit.HttpAuthHandler;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class BaiBrowser extends Activity
{
private static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;

private WebView webView;
public String URL, USERNAME, PASSWORD;
EditText user,password;
private int refreshrate;
private String noRefresh;
private String URLPref;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.webpage);         
    //Get webview 
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1); 
    URL = getURL();
    USERNAME = getUser();
    PASSWORD = getPassword();
    startWebView(URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);
}

@SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled") 
private void startWebView(final String url, final String Username, final String Password) 
{
    //Create new webview Client to show progress dialog
    //When opening a url or click on link          
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
    {      
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;

        //If you will not use this method url links are opeen in new brower not in webview
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);                              
            return true;
        }

        //Show loader on url load
        public void onLoadResource (WebView view, String url) 
        {
            if (progressDialog == null) {
                // in standard case YourActivity.this
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(BaiBrowser.this);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
                progressDialog.show();
            }
        }
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
        {
            try
            {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) 
                {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    progressDialog = null;
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Log.e("ProgressDialog Error", ""+ex);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedHttpAuthRequest(WebView view, final HttpAuthHandler handler, String host, String realm) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub              
            handler.proceed(Username, Password);    
        } 

        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) 
        {
            if (errorCode == 401) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(null, "Need Your Credentials", 2000).show();
            }
        }
    }); 

     // Javascript inabled on webview  
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 

    // Other webview options

    webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);  
    webView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(url, null, Username, Password);         
    /*
     String summary = "<html><body>You scored <b>192</b> points.</body></html>";
     webview.loadData(summary, "text/html", null); 
     */         
    //Load url in webview        
    webView.loadUrl(url);
}     
// Open previous opened link from history on webview when back button pressed     
@Override
// Detect when the back button is pressed
public void onBackPressed() 
{
    if(webView.canGoBack()) 
    {
        webView.goBack();
    } 
    else 
    {
        // Let the system handle the back button
         finish();
         System.exit(0); 
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) 
{
   // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
   return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
{  
    switch (item.getItemId()) 
    {  
        case R.id.settings:  
                Intent prefIntent = new Intent(this, Preferences.class);
                startActivityForResult(prefIntent, RESULT_SETTINGS);
                    break;     

        case R.id.exit:              
                     finish();
                     System.exit(0);                    
        default:  
                    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);  
    } 
    return true;
} 

public String getURL() 
{
    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("prefUrl", sharedPrefs.getString("prefUrl", "http://10.227.100.8:8080/"));
    prefEditor.commit();
    String Url = sharedPrefs.getString("prefUrl", "http://10.227.100.8:8080/");
    return Url;
}

public String getUser() 
{
    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("Username", sharedPrefs.getString("Username", "BRANDIXLK\\BAIICTIntern4"));
    prefEditor.commit();
    String User = sharedPrefs.getString("Username", "BRANDIXLK\\BAIICTIntern4");
    return User;
}

public String getPassword() 
{
    final SharedPreferences sharedPrefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefEditor = sharedPrefs.edit();
    prefEditor.putString("Password", sharedPrefs.getString("Password", "pass@1234"));
    prefEditor.commit();
    String User = sharedPrefs.getString("Password", "pass@1234");
    return User;
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode) 
    {
        case RESULT_SETTINGS:   final String URL = getURL();
                                final String User = getUser();
                                final String Pass = getPassword();

                                new CountDownTimer(365 * 24 * 60 * 60, 60000) 
                                {
                                 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
                                 {
                                     startWebView(URL, User, Pass);
                                 }

                                 public void onFinish() 
                                 {
                                     startWebView(URL, User, Pass);
                                 }
                                }.start();

                                break;
    }
}

}
```

preferences.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_url_setting" >
            <EditTextPreference 
                    android:title="@string/pref_url" 
                    android:summary="@string/pref_url_summary" 
                    android:defaultValue="http://10.227.100.8:8080/"
                    android:key="prefUrl"/>
        </PreferenceCategory>

        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_other_setting" >    
            <EditTextPreference 
                    android:title="@string/pref_sync_frequency" 
                    android:summary="@string/pref_sync_frequency_summary" 
                    android:key="prefRefreshRate"/>
        </PreferenceCategory>

        <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/authentication" >  
            <EditTextPreference 
                    android:title="@string/username" 
                    android:summary="@string/username_summary" 
                    android:defaultValue="BRANDIXLK\\BAIICTIntern4"
                    android:key="Username"/>   
            <EditTextPreference 
                    android:title="@string/password" 
                    android:summary="@string/password_summary"
                    android:defaultValue="pass@1234"
                    android:key="Password"/>
        </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Menu.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@+id/settings"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_preferences"
          android:title="@string/settings">        
    </item>
    <item android:id="@+id/exit"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_exit"
          android:title="@string/exit">

    </item>


</menu>
```

NOTE : Authentication is successful, if i pass the credential values directly in "handler.proceed(Username, Password);". But passing values to it failed. Please guide me to complete the project.

Comment: Try posting the minimal code that is relevant to the problem you are facing. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Please check once that i posted minimal code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the answer, i just placed the line of code `webView.setHttpAuthUsernamePassword(url, null, Username, Password);` above the method

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() 
{ ---------
  -------
  -------
}
```

Thanks